# Rails use default layout for controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm new with Ruby on Rails and i can't figure out how to use a layout for a controller.

Actually, i have got in my views "layout" directory with application.html.erb inside.

In this file, i have got all my template, inside this there is a div class.
Inside i would like to call my "pages" controller.

My route.rb is

```
root 'pages#show', page: 'home'
get 'pages/:page' => 'pages/#show'
```

What i have when i go on my website is of course the default layout.
Now i would like to call every page (ex pages/home.html.erb) inside the div in layouts/application.html.erb

How should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need get into this guide [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

And if I understand you right, you whant to do somethisng like

```
...
<div class='my_div'>
 <%= yeild %>
</div>
...
```

Comment: That guide will help a lot, I still use it all the time. Your `pages` templates should go into a `app/views/pages`, that's where rails looks and they should be named to match the controller action, `show.html.erb` for example. Also the yield needs to be erb-ized; `<%= yield %>`.